# How to cancel an in-progress animation in Leaflet

Tags: animation, leaflet

I am working with Leafet (currently beta 2 for 1.0) and am performing some lengthy animated map moves with code like this:

```
    myMap.setView([someLat,someLng], myMap.getZoom(), {"pan":{"animate":true, "duration":10});
```

I want to be able to stop this animation while it is in progress. Searching through the leaflet API, for both the current version and for the beta I don't find any method for doing so. So how can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling another `setView` using the current map center should stop the animation in progress:

```
map.setView(map.getCenter(), map.getZoom(), {"animate": false});
```

Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/nathansnider/4v2L0uze/